# Installing Grafana Panel Plugin

Tags: grafana

I am attempting to install the piechart plugin on my Grafana v2.5 environment and no matter what I do the panel does now show as an option in the UI. I cloned the repository to /var/lib/grafana/plugins as documented and restarted the grafana-server service and that did not work. I also tried putting the plugin in a separate directory and referencing it as:

```
[plugin.piechart]
path = /home/usr/share/grafana/panel-plugin-piechart
```

I made sure that the grafana service has ownership of the plugin directory, and checked the grafana logs but it did not have useful information.

https://github.com/grafana/panel-plugin-piechart

Answer (score 0):

---

You will need Grafana master based on the release date of the plugin.

Confirmed here - https://groups.io/g/grafana/message/1181

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to upgrade your Grafana. This is very seamless operation - just install a new package on top of the old one. You can back up through copy /var/lib/grafana/grafana.db for safety before doing that.

Comment: Since the post was over a year ago, yeah upgrading makes sense.

Comment: as you can see, nobody helps this guy. so maybe he just sitting and waiting for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission of the files in plugins directory,
all the files of the plugin should be in its directory, i.e. every plugin should be contained its own directory
if the plugins directory has any package.json file or webpack.config.js available outside then also your plugins will fail to load.
the above mentioned files are part of every panel plugins and should only exist in their respective directories.

execute "chown" and set the owner to grafana:grafana   group:user

(by default root is the owner of the files and directories.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Grafana as a standalone service or in a docker container?
If running as a service directly you can visit the Grafana community page and find the plugin installation instructions from there.
https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-piechart-panel
(Verified on Grafana version 6.x.x & 7)

If running within a dockerized service you need to copy the plugin in your workspace and specify the directory within the docker image so it can locate the plugin from there. You can do this by using the environment variables and mention these within a docker-compose file

> GF_PATHS_PLUGINS  /var/lib/grafana/plugins
> https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/configure-docker/

I have been able to work with both these options